# Why can't easy install get mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, windows-7, easy-install

I am using Windows 7 and trying to install mysql-python.

```
> easy_install MySQL-python  
Searching for MySQL-python  
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/  
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/  
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python  
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.3  
Downloading http://download.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/mysql-python/MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz  
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz  
Running MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir
c:\users\develo~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gwhmn3\MySQL-python-1.2.3\egg-dist-tmp-co6v2g  
error: The system cannot find the file specified
```

There is an error and it is not installed.

Comment: what is the problem you are getting??

Comment: error: The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Windows, why not just goto [python-mysql installation files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/) and download the installer and install it.

Answer (score 0):

i found a way around this problem.
i downloaded mysql-python windows binary from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python)
installed it and now it working fine.